# Scikit image: resize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'anti_aliasing'

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to use the resize function using aliasing exactly as described in the documentation: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html

```
from skimage.transform import resize
im_test = resize(im_test, (im_test.shape[0] / 3, im_test.shape[1] / 3),anti_aliasing=True)
```

However this returns:

> Scikit image: resize() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'anti_aliasing'

What is the reason for this? Is anti_aliasing on by default? What is the best way to resize an image with anti aliasing if this function can't be used?

Answer (score 2):

Checking the code [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blame/ce13ed994cda73945104862d424c1ede7092d89d/skimage/transform/_warps.py#L77) with git blame, it seems it was introduced on 19.09.2017.

The only release version supporting this currently should be: [v0.13.1](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/releases/tag/v0.13.1), **which you will need then!**

For checking, what kind of version you are using currently, i recommend opening your interpreter (of your used python-distribution) and do:

```python
import skimage as sk
sk.__version__
# '0.13.0' i would not be able to use it, it seems
```

Comment: What? The above is a check (which will work in a jupyter notebook too). No special import-style. Just check which version you have and if it's not 0.13.1, you probably need to upgrade. Without using virtual-environments, you can only have one version installed at a time.

Comment: This is a new feature that will be available in the next release, 0.14.

Comment: I have `0.13.1` and anti_aliasing isn't available yet

Comment: True. If you check the source code to which the answer is referring, it's simply not there. The answer is incorrect.

Comment: I cloned and installed the master branch. That seemed to work. (version 0.14dev

Comment: You can simply upgrade scikit-image package using: `pip3 install --upgrade scikit-image`

Answer (score 0):

there are two sets of documentation

1) http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize

2)http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.11.x/api/skimage.transform.html#resize

the second one doesn't accept anti_aliasing as a parameter and is the 0.11 version, the one that accepts anti aliasing is 0.14
looks like older version uses a box filter while resizing,and all pixels have equal weight